# Why doesn't python regard two discrete instances of a django model to be the same object?

Tags: python, django, operators

(Using django as an example; the ForeignKey is implicit in the example)

```
>>> from coconuts.models import Coconut, Swallow
>>> c1 = Coconut.objects.get(id=1)
>>> s = Swallow.objects.get(id=1)
>>> c2 = s.coconuts_carried.filter(id=1)
>>> c1 == c2
True
>>> c1 is c2
False
```

My understanding is that 'is' tests identity, while == tests equality.  In this case, c1 and c2 are the same exact object.  Why "isn't" they the same thing?

Comment: Obviously, becaus they are distinct objects that consider each other equal. Or are you asking why they aren't the same objects?

Comment: Yes, I guess it turns out that I'm asking why they aren't the same object.  I'll edit the title to reflect that.

Comment: Theoretically django could keep a index of objects it has created from the database and instead of creating a new object every time, it could search in the index for a existing object and return that. That would be a waste of everyone's time tough, as this would only generate a lot of overhead and complexity for next to no gain. It's simply much easier to return a new object every time.

Comment: Personally I found this behaviour of the Django ORM very confusing. The Storm ORM does this differently, IIRC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is` compares python objects, not objects in your database. each query returns a new python objects, and so c and c2 are different.

to see this, try changing some of the properties of c or c2. Only one of them will change.

as can be seen from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#comparing-objects),

```
c == c2
```

is equivalent to

```
c.id == c2.id
```

Comment: They are new python objects?  They are the same exact object; ie, the same instance of the same class.  I guess I don't understand what a "new python object" is in this context.

Comment: @jMyles: If they were the same instance of the same class, than `c1 is c2` would evaluate to true. So your program proves that this is a wrong assumption.

Comment: Model.objects.get fetches a row from your database, and instantiates a new model instance with its data

Answer (score 1):

They are the same objects if you talk about "database objects", but not "python objects".

`a is b` will be `True` if `a` and `b` is the *same Python object instance* - they have the same identity. The `is` operator can not be overloaded, so it works the same with all Python objects.

To understand whats going on here, check `id(c1)` and `id(c2)` in an interactive Python shell. You will notice they have different identities.

`a == b` will be `True` if `a` and `b` are considered equal. The `==` operator can be overloaded, so different objects behaves differently when being compared. [When comparing Django model objects, they are considered equal when they are the same type, and their primary keys are equal.](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/base.py#L384)

Answer (score 0):

If we both pirate a game from the same website and burn it to CD, my CD is not the same CD as yours, even if the contents are identical and come from the same source.

Same idea here. Access to the database creates another Python object each time with the same data.

Comment: I don't love this analogy.  In the case of two django objects, running .save() on either of them affects the database in the same way.  IE, they don't merely have the same source, they also have the same underlying identity as pieces of knowledge, although apparently not as python objects.